# i have a rss feed and want to display its data into textview

Tags: android, rss, textview

can anybody tell how to parse a horoscope from [this URL](http://www.astrocenter.com/us/horoscope-daily.aspx?When=0&ZSign=1&Af=0) and get its value in a textview. i go through many examples but i dint get the logic as i new to android. all examples are baded in list view to get the feed but  and load data's in list view but i have the feed and want the data to display in text view. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can try this example you will get idea how to parse rss feed url
http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/

Comment: i have already go through that, but i dont want to use listview and webView to show the content and dont want arrayadapter cause i have the url and show the content to related horoscope sign into textview on button click. that's it.